# Hide confidential data in iOS file system

Tags: ios, security, file-management

I have created an iPad app which downloads some confidential data and stores it in the document folder.

I was reading about the security of data on an iPad, and I found that there are some applications which reveal all the data and folders of an app.

Is there any way to avoid that, and to secure my data or a whole folder?

Comment: check this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/45645/ios-app-security-analysis-part-1/

Comment: @pawan :Thank you very much..this is very much use full information

Answer (score 0):

For storing confidential information use `KeyChainItemWrapper`